# How to use Universal.System or Material.System in latest Qt 5.8?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.8

I'm playing around with Qt 5.8 RC and the new attribute System introduced in both Universal and Material themes.

However when designing a customizable app, one can choose Universal or Material in combination with Dark, Light or System. How can I know that System is actually not the string "System" but either "Dark" or "Light"?

Here's what I'm trying to build (settings.qml):
[image: Miam-Player-QML]

```
RadioButton {
    text: qsTr("Light")
    checked: appSettings.theme === "Light"
    ButtonGroup.group: modeBG
    onClicked: {
        appSettings.theme = "Light"
        appSettings.background = "white"
        appSettings.menuPaneColor = "#eeeeee"
    }
}
RadioButton {
    text: qsTr("Dark")
    checked: appSettings.theme === "Dark"
    ButtonGroup.group: modeBG
    onClicked: {
        appSettings.theme = "Dark"
        appSettings.background = "black"
        appSettings.menuPaneColor = "#171717"
    }
}
RadioButton {
    text: qsTr("System theme")
    ButtonGroup.group: modeBG
    onClicked: {
        appSettings.theme = "System"
        //appSettings.background = "black"
        //appSettings.menuPaneColor = "#171717"
    }
}
```

Obviously, the following code which used to work with "hard" values no longer works (main.qml):

```
ToolButton {
    id: burgerMenu
    checkable: appSettings.burgerMenuIsChecked
    contentItem: Image {
        fillMode: Image.Pad
        horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter
        source: "qrc:/images/" + appSettings.style + "/" + appSettings.theme + "/drawer.png"
    }
    ...
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You could specify different [configuration files](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html) and try to do that check in C++

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#material-theme-attached-prop) says:

> Setting the theme to System chooses either the light or dark theme
>   based on the system theme colors. However, when reading the value of
>   the theme property, the value is never System, but the actual theme.

So, if you check the values of `Material.theme` and `Universal.theme`, both should return their effective values, rather than the value that you set.

Comment: Hmm.. That's strange because    onClicked: { console.log(Material.theme) } always returns qml: 0 in Qt Creator

Comment: `Material.theme: Material.Dark; Component.onCompleted: print(Material.theme)` prints `1` for me. Setting `Material.theme: Material.System` will use whatever your system is using, so if that's a light theme, it's always going to return `0`: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/material/qquickmaterialstyle_p.h#n104

Comment: I think the RC that I have downloaded isn't working well. When I start a new project from scratch using Assistant (and putting latest release number in imports), `Accent=BlueGrey` in `qtquickcontrols2.conf` doesn't work: I see an error in console, `Theme=Dark` or `Theme=Light` is fine, but `Theme=System` always fallback on light.

Comment: I can't do much without having a complete example to try out, sorry.

Comment: You can check with Gallery example : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-gallery-example.html, it has a `qtquickcontrols2.conf` file.

Comment: With regards to the original question though, `Theme=System` always resulting in the light theme makes perfect sense if your system is using a light theme. I don't see the issue there.

Comment: Indeed, but on Windows now you can set Dark or Light, and this is reflected in app like Calculator, but never in Qt Apps. So I've opened an issue here : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58055 which is basically this thread.